# LWJGL - Failed to locate library: liblwjgl.dylib in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, macos, lwjgl

I'm trying to run the example code from https://www.lwjgl.org/guide on macOS Big Sur 11.6 (Apple M1 chip). I imported all of the necessary libraries and wrote `-XstartOnFirstThread` in VM options and got this error:

```
[LWJGL] Failed to load a library. Possible solutions:
    a) Add the directory that contains the shared library to -Djava.library.path or -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath.
    b) Add the JAR that contains the shared library to the classpath.
[LWJGL] Enable debug mode with -Dorg.lwjgl.util.Debug=true for better diagnostics.
[LWJGL] Enable the SharedLibraryLoader debug mode with -Dorg.lwjgl.util.DebugLoader=true for better diagnostics.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to locate library: liblwjgl.dylib
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:162)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:62)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:50)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.<clinit>(MemoryUtil.java:97)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Pointer$Default.<clinit>(Pointer.java:67)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Callback.<clinit>(Callback.java:41)
    at com.company.HelloWorld.init(HelloWorld.java:38)
    at com.company.HelloWorld.run(HelloWorld.java:23)
    at com.company.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:113)
```

I've tried manually extracting natives from other jars to a separate "native/" folder in the project folder and passing `-Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath=native` as a VM option but it changed absolutely nothing. I don't know if I should add the "native/" folder to libraries but it also seems to have no impact on the result.

Here is the example code from the LWJGL website:

```
package com.company;
import org.lwjgl.*;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.system.*;

import java.nio.*;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.*;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;

public class HelloWorld {

    // The window handle
    private long window;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello LWJGL " + Version.getVersion() + "!");

        init();
        loop();

        // Free the window callbacks and destroy the window
        glfwFreeCallbacks(window);
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);

        // Terminate GLFW and free the error callback
        glfwTerminate();
        glfwSetErrorCallback(null).free();
    }

    private void init() {
        // Setup an error callback. The default implementation
        // will print the error message in System.err.
        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();

        // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
        if ( !glfwInit() )
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

        // Configure GLFW
        glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE); // the window will be resizable

        // Create the window
        window = glfwCreateWindow(300, 300, "Hello World!", NULL, NULL);
        if ( window == NULL )
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");

        // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (window, key, scancode, action, mods) -> {
            if ( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE )
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true); // We will detect this in the rendering loop
        });

        // Get the thread stack and push a new frame
        try ( MemoryStack stack = stackPush() ) {
            IntBuffer pWidth = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*
            IntBuffer pHeight = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*

            // Get the window size passed to glfwCreateWindow
            glfwGetWindowSize(window, pWidth, pHeight);

            // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
            GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());

            // Center the window
            glfwSetWindowPos(
                window,
                (vidmode.width() - pWidth.get(0)) / 2,
                (vidmode.height() - pHeight.get(0)) / 2
            );
        } // the stack frame is popped automatically

        // Make the OpenGL context current
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        // Enable v-sync
        glfwSwapInterval(1);

        // Make the window visible
        glfwShowWindow(window);
    }

    private void loop() {
        // This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
        // OpenGL context, or any context that is managed externally.
        // LWJGL detects the context that is current in the current thread,
        // creates the GLCapabilities instance and makes the OpenGL
        // bindings available for use.
        GL.createCapabilities();

        // Set the clear color
        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        // Run the rendering loop until the user has attempted to close
        // the window or has pressed the ESCAPE key.
        while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose(window) ) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the framebuffer

            glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers

            // Poll for window events. The key callback above will only be
            // invoked during this call.
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HelloWorld().run();
    }

}
```

jars:

```
lwjgl-assimp-javadoc.jar    lwjgl-nanovg-sources.jar    lwjgl-par-javadoc.jar
lwjgl-assimp-sources.jar    lwjgl-nanovg.jar            lwjgl-par-sources.jar
lwjgl-assimp.jar            lwjgl-nuklear-javadoc.jar   lwjgl-par.jar
lwjgl-bgfx-javadoc.jar      lwjgl-nuklear-sources.jar   lwjgl-sources.jar
lwjgl-bgfx-sources.jar      lwjgl-nuklear.jar           lwjgl-stb-javadoc.jar
lwjgl-bgfx.jar              lwjgl-openal-javadoc.jar    lwjgl-stb-sources.jar
lwjgl-glfw-javadoc.jar      lwjgl-openal-sources.jar    lwjgl-stb.jar
lwjgl-glfw-sources.jar      lwjgl-openal.jar            lwjgl-vulkan-javadoc.jar
lwjgl-glfw.jar              lwjgl-opengl-javadoc.jar    lwjgl-vulkan-sources.jar
lwjgl-javadoc.jar           lwjgl-opengl-sources.jar    lwjgl-vulkan.jar
lwjgl-nanovg-javadoc.jar    lwjgl-opengl.jar            lwjgl.jar
```

natives:

```
lwjgl-assimp-natives-macos.jar  lwjgl-natives-macos.jar         lwjgl-par-natives-macos.jar
lwjgl-bgfx-natives-macos.jar    lwjgl-nuklear-natives-macos.jar lwjgl-stb-natives-macos.jar
lwjgl-glfw-natives-macos.jar    lwjgl-openal-natives-macos.jar  lwjgl-vulkan-natives-macos.jar
lwjgl-nanovg-natives-macos.jar  lwjgl-opengl-natives-macos.jar
```

(downloaded from https://www.lwjgl.org/customize)

Comment: @KaiBurjack By "necessary" I mean the ones that are used in this code and by "imported" I mean that I added them by going to File > Project Structure > Libraries > New Project Library (+ sign) > Java and selecting the folder with the jars. How do I add the classpath?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You selected the wrong natives in the LWJGL customizer for your CPU architecture. You selected macOS x64, however M1 is not x86 but arm. The current* LWJGL release 3.2.3 **does not support macOS arm**.
You have to use the 3.3.0 Early Access version on the LWJGL customizer and then select the macOS arm64 native.

EDIT:

* LWJGL 3.3.0 is already released and hence one does not necessarily need to choose "Early Access" version anymore. Both x64 and arm natives can now be selected in a stable release version of LWJGL.